# Non-Linear Beltrami Vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider two concentric toruses, and let $\Sigma$ be the domain interior to the greater torus and exterior to the smaller torus. Is it possible to find a vector field $\mathbf{b}$ satisfying the following conditions:

1. $\mathrm{div} \, \mathbf{b}=0$ in $\Sigma$;
2. $\mathbf{b}$ is everywhere tangent to $\partial \Sigma$; and
3. $\mathrm{curl} \, \mathbf{b} = \lambda(\mathbf{x}) \mathbf{b}$ in $\Sigma$.

Thank you

Comment: Is $\lambda$ prescribed to us? If yes, what do we know about it? If no, have you tried to find a field with zero curl and divergence?

Comment: No $\lambda$ is an arbitrary continuous function. In Wikipedia (page on Hairy ball theorem) there is a picture of field everywhere tangent to the torus, but I don't know if we can extend it to be Beltrami.

Comment: Would not the two-dimensional example $\dfrac{x_2\mathbf{i}-x_1\mathbf{j}}{x_1^2+x_2^2}$ work just as well in three dimensions?

Comment: Maybe after you compose it with a map $\pi$ which sends $\mathbb{R}^2$ to the torus.

Comment: No, I mean $F(x)=\dfrac{x_2\mathbf{i}-x_1\mathbf{j}}{x_1^2+x_2^2}$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^3$. Does not this satisfy 1,2,3? I'm taking the $x_3$-axis to be the axis of symmetry of $\Sigma$.

Comment: No. How can this two dimensional field be everywhere tangent to the torus, which does not lie in a single plane?

Comment: I don't why not. The flow lines of $F$ are circles centered on the $x_3$-axis. The domain is rotationally symmetric. Hence, flow lines do not exit the domain.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Is this Beltrami?

Comment: The curl is zero, and so is the divergence...

Comment: And in the case of $\lambda$ prescribed, what do you do?

Comment: Delete my comments and abandon this thread, I suppose.